# The Love Letter Mystery

Tags: algorithm, palindrome

At Hackerrank.com, [the love letter mystery](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-love-letter-mystery) is a simple programming problem, which I already solved.

My solution involved calculating the palindrome and counting the number of operations to do it.  On Hackerrank, they have another approach, which I don't understand completely:

> Given a string, you have to convert it into a palindrome using a certain set of operations.
>
> Let's assume that the length of the string is L, and the characters are indexed from 0 to L-1. The string will be palindrome, only if the characters at index i and the characters at index (L-1-i) are same. So, we need to ensure that the characters for all such indices are same.
>
> Let's assume that one such set of indices can be denoted by A' and B'. It is given that it takes one operation in decreasing value of a character by 1. So, the total number of operations will be |A'-B'|.We need to calculate this for all such pairs of indices, which can be done in a single for loop. Take a look at the setter's code.

I understand everything up until they mention that the total number of operations are **|A'-B'|, the absolute value between the two indices.**  Why is that?  For some reason, my head is being thicker (than usual).

Thanks!

======== EDIT ==========

Hey guys, thanks for your input. I thought that this stackexchange site would had been more appropiate than stackoverflow. Is there any stackexchange site where this question is more appropiate?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming contest or a question about code golfing.

Comment: @ProgramFOX It's a question about a programming puzzle, though, isn't it?

Comment: @m.buettner It's a question about a specific approach to solve a programming puzzle, but it has nothing to do with code.

Comment: @m.buettner: The [help center](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says that all questions on this site should have an objective primary winning criterion, and that "tips for golfing in some language" is the only exception to this rule.

Comment: @Dennis this is currently being discussed in a lot of detail in chat and on meta, and there are a fairly large number of people who would welcome more non-challenge posts on the site, as it is still a site *about* Programming Puzzles & Code Golf (in addition to being a site *for* Programming Puzzles & Code Golf). As long as no consensus on this has been reached, I'd say closing or downvoting such questions is up to everyone's own opinion, but *my* opinion is we should welcome these questions, because they seem very much on topic to me and could well increase our traffic.

Comment: @m.buettner I agree that we should welcome non-challenge questions, but this question is more related to algorithms than to programming and code.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your input.  I thought that this stackexchange site would had been more appropiate than stackoverflow.  Is there any stackexchange site where this question is more appropiate?

Comment: @dornad I maintain it's on topic here, but until 4 other people decide to vote to reopen this question that's not of much help to you. In any case, as for your actual question, I suspect that there is a typo in their answer, and that A' and B' refer to the character values at the current pair of indices. What does their code do?

Comment: @m.buettner: I think those questions would make a nice addition to our site and I did not downvote this one, but I'll always vote to close according to the rules laid out in the help center.

Comment: My best guess is **no**, you can't ask this question at Stack Exchange. You can't ask it here (because it is closed), and I don't know any other Stack Exchange site about programming puzzles.

Comment: HackerRank has its own discussion pages for each problem. [Here's the discussion page for the problem you mentioned.](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w3/challenges/the-love-letter-mystery/forum/questions)

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm might make more sense with a sample implementation to look at (here, in Python):

```
S = raw_input()
L = len(S)
T = 0
for i in range(L/2):
  A = ord(S[i])
  B = ord(S[L-1-i])
  T += abs(A-B)
print T
```

Let's review the problem description. Each character decrement (e.g. `--'b' == 'a'`) counts as a single operation. The problem is to determine the number of operations required to transform the input string into a palindrome.

The algorithm iterates over half the string, and compares the ordinal value of the character at the current index with that of the character across from it (in its mirrored position). If they are not the same, the one that is larger needs to be decremented, but it doesn't actually need to be checked which is which. Taking the absolute value of the difference will produce the correct number of operations needed regardless.

I think a source of confusion might be the wording, *"Let's assume that **one such set of indices** can be denoted by A' and B'."* I believe that the author intended *A'* and *B'* to refer to the *characters* at each of these indices, and not the indices themselves. If they had actually meant to refer to the indices, the algorithm would return the same value for any given string length, which is obviously incorrect.

A golfed version might look like this:

```
s=map(ord,raw_input())
print sum(abs(s[i]-s[~i])for i in range(len(s)/2))
```

I suspect Ruby might be a bit shorter, because indexing a string returns the ordinal value, rather than the individual character.